# remove references of a module in react native

Tags: react-native, npm

I am stuck with an odd problem, I am trying to get rid of react-native-pdf so

- I unlink it ( `react-native unlink react-native-pdf`)
- I remove it from node modules ( `npm uninstall react-native-pdf`)

Problem now is that when I try to run my app is giving me this error 
[image]

and my terminal look like this 
[image]

did I miss to do somenthing?

Comment: Now, Just please remove `react-native-pdf` from package.json then run command `npm install` i think so some of dependancy modules removed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite sure about iOS, but for Android here are a few things you can check as react-native unlink sometimes doesn't unlink it properly:

#### android/settings.gradle

Delete any includes and project declarations to ':react-native-pdf'

#### android/app/build.gradle

Delete any compile declarations to ':react-native-pdf' under "dependencies"

#### android/app/src/main/java/com/[your_app_name]/MainApplication.java

In the getPackages() method, make sure you delete any references to ':react-native-pdf' such as `new ReactNativePdfPackage()` or something similar. You may also have to delete any related imports.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In addition to that what I did in order to make it work 
react-native unlink react-native-pdf; npm uninstall react-native-pdf; watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/  && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache